Is there a consensus on what it means for a machlochet (dispute) to "endure"? Or is even this, ironically, a topic of debate?
I only just learned about this wonderful passage from Pirke Avot. And I see that it is, of course, invoked often when discussing the topic of conflicts and arguments. Most seem to agree on the meaning of L'shem shamayim (לְשֵׁם שָׁמַיִם) as being essentially "for the right reasons" or alternatively "for the sake of truth". But I see disagreement on what it means that the dispute or machlochet (מַחֲלֹקֶת) will exist ain sof l'hitkayam (אֵין סוֹפָהּ לְהִתְקַיֵּם)---with no end in what is to come.
A positive interpretation is that if our goal in arguing is to uncover essential truths, then the argument is likely and perhaps even should be eternal for it is a way we strive to achieve ma'alin b'kodesh, to get to a higher place. This seems to be the most common interpretation.
I also stumbled upon a negative interpretation in this drash. Rabbi Yissocher Frand argues that if we engage in conflict over essential truths, we will simply fight forever and that such conflicts should be avoided. At least, that's how I read it.
Is there a generally accepted interpretation of L'shem shamayim and especially of ain sof l'hitkayam? Or are the meanings, ironically or intentionally, the topic of machlochet?

"But I see disagreement on what it means that the dispute or machlochet (מַחֲלֹקֶת) will exist ain sof l'hitkayam (אֵין סוֹפָהּ לְהִתְקַיֵּם)---with no end in what is to come." (1) You're mistransliterating "אֵין סוֹפָהּ לְהִתְקַיֵּם". It should be "ain sofa l'hitkayam". (2) "אֵין סוֹפָהּ לְהִתְקַיֵּם" doesn't mean "will exist... with no end in what is to come". It means "will not endure", literally "it's end (סוֹפָהּ) is not (אֵין) to exist/stand/endure (לְהִתְקַיֵּם)".

"I also stumbled upon a negative interpretation in this drash." Do you mean the one that starts "Rabbi Yisrael Salanter once said whimsically in homiletic fashion...", and reiterates later "That is what Rav Yisrael Salanter whimsically said the Mishna alludes to"? I didn't read through the rest of the article, but from that section, I think you're misunderstanding both R. Salanter and R. Frand. The later says "[a]n argument for the sake of Heaven is the worst type of machlokes" because "It goes on forever". They're being whimsical.
